# GridView : how to increase a value from a cell by one on row updating?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

- I have a simple gridview and sqldatasource1 to bind from tableData to
  gridview.

A column called "Haha" type int . the default value in the datatable for that cell is 0 .
On row update I want to increase the value by one.

So right now in the cell the value is 0 . If I just press the update button then the value in the data table will be 1 and if I update again it will be 2 and so on.

I've tried this code but is not working , I mean nothing is changed.

```
GridViewRow currentRow = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex];
        String intColumnText = currentRow.Cells[2].Text; //assuming it's the first cell
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(intColumnText, out value))
        {
            //if you want to increment that value and override the old
            currentRow.Cells[2].Text = (value++).ToString();
        } 
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: how this question is related to SQL?
are you fetching data from database or storing this data(updated one) into tables .. ?

Comment: I have a database and a table , I'm binding with sqldatasource the information from table to grdiview.

Comment: that is what i was asking and expecting .. so one thing .. do you want to update your database as well while clicking that button .. ??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    GridViewRow currentRow = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex];
    String intColumnText = currentRow.Cells[2].Text; //assuming it's the first cell
    int value;
    if (int.TryParse(intColumnText, out value))
    {
        //if you want to increment that value and override the old

((DataTable)((GridView)sender).DataSource).Rows[CurrentRow.RowIndex][2]=(value +1).ToString();
    } 
}
```